# popup window instead of popup menu

Tags: android, popup

I want to show the `popup window` in my application on click of image(Menu) But My problem is that I want to show it according to my `height` and `width` not the default what it comes,

here is my code,

```
ivmainmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
             = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
              .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindow, null);  
                     final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow();  

                     popupWindow.showAsDropDown(ivmainmenu, 50, -30);

           }});
```

here is  My xml file, This xml I want to show in my application,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#000000">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tvpopupwork"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="OUR WORK"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right|center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvwork1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:text="»"
                    android:textSize="20dp" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tvpopupabout"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="SERVICES"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right|center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvabout1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="»"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tvpopupservices"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABOUT"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right|center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvservices1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:text="»"
                    android:textSize="20dp" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tvpopupcontact"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="CONTACT"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right|center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvwork1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:text="»"
                    android:textSize="20dp" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me, 
thank you.

Comment: You can go for Custom Dialog as per your need. You would be able to modify it according to your need

Comment: but i want in menu can you do it?

Comment: yes you can open it on click of menu item'

Comment: can you give me the code of it?

Comment: I can give you just the idea.It is now upto you how you want to implement the code.Search out for examples of Custom dialog on Internet.You will get plenty of stuffs..

Comment: here is one example http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88&aaid=111

Comment: ok thanks... I'll do it, but i want to set the height and width ?

Comment: you can do everything you need by modifying code of the code of Custom dialog's xml code

Comment: @akky777 Here is Another one ...http://androidituts.com/android-popup-window-tutorial-2/

Answer (score -2):

insted of  popupWindow.showAsDropDown(ivmainmenu, 50, -30);
`popupWindow.setHeight(200);
popupWindow.setWidth(400);`